# android image layout size

Tags: android, image, layout

[image]

from the above image,how can remove the white space surrounding the image

imageview layout is

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/list_image"
android:layout_width="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"
android:layout_height="@android:dimen/app_icon_size"

android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Comment: It's not clear, do you mean you want the fit the image width with the layout that contains it?

Comment: a layout can't fit an image. i don't get your question.

Comment: the image fits in the layout, I need to get rid of the white space surrounding the image.

Comment: The white space or the gray?

Comment: the rectangle white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your image `android:adjustViewBounds=true`

If still not working, change layout size to `wrap_content`

Comment: the original image has the whitespace?

Comment: No,its without whitespace.

Comment: BTW its a system application image. the Image shown on the launcher does not show the white space but when added to listview it does.

Comment: In that case, you should have some layout with white background, so check the parent layout. and set background to transparent

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with nine patches:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

From the comments below your question I understood that you want to get rid of the white space surrounding the your Image, Actually this has nothing to do with `Android`.

You need to modify your image using [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/).

Once you download the software from the link above follow the steps below.

1) Open Your Image with Gimp.

2) Add an `Alfa canal` to your Image. 
  Right Click > Layer > Transparency> Add Alfa Channel

3) Select the white space on your image, by clicking on that white space using the `fuzzy select tool` from your toolbox

[image]

4) Delete the white space with the delete button.

5) Save your Image as a .png